# Converting *= to LEFT OUTER JOIN correctly with two aliases and two comparisons

Tags: sql, syntax, left-join, sybase, outer-join

I want to convert the SQL syntax of `*=` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Here is the original syntax:

```
SELECT 
    a.col1,
    a.col2,
    b.col1,
    b.col2,
    b.col3,
    b.col4
FROM
    tableA AS a,
    tableB AS b
WHERE 
    a.col1 *= b.col1 AND
    a.col2 *= b.col2 AND
    b.col3 = "xxx"
    b.col4 = "yyy"
```

I'm trying the following, but it returns way too many rows as a result of join. What I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT 
    a.col1,
    a.col2,
    b.col1,
    b.col2,
    b.col3,
    b.col4
FROM
    tableA AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB AS b ON a.col1 = b.col1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB ON a.col2 = b.col2   
WHERE 
    b.col3 = "xxx"
    b.col4 = "yyy"
```

Comment: I could be wrong but those stand-alone conditions on `b` in the `WHERE` clause (`col3` and `col4`) could be transforming the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. They certainly will in the "after" form (your attempt + answers).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Perhaps that's the case. Could you explain a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: You're missing a boolean connective in the WHEREs of your queries. This is one of the reasons you should always supply a [mcve].

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Transact-SQL allows `=` involving the non-`*` table and uses it as part of the `left join` criterion not a later `where`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below sample code

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, b.col1, b.col2, b.col3, b.col4
FROM tableA AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB AS b ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2
WHERE 
b.col3 = "xxx" AND b.col4 = "yyy"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AND` in the `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT 
    a.col1,
    a.col2,
    b.col1,
    b.col2,
    b.col3,
    b.col4
FROM
    tableA AS a

LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB AS b ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2   
WHERE 
    b.col3 = "xxx"
    b.col4 = "yyy"
```

Answer (score 0):

One `LEFT JOIN` enough. Could you try this

```
SELECT 
    a.col1,
    a.col2,
    b.col1,
    b.col2,
    b.col3,
    b.col4
FROM
    tableA AS a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB AS b ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2 
WHERE 
    b.col3 = "xxx"
    AND b.col4 = "yyy"
```

Comment: @sam - you shouldn't be getting "exactly the same results" with this (or Ofir's answer) since your existing code contained a second join that was then entirely unconstrained by its `ON` clause - meaning every row of `a LEFT JOIN b` was then joined again to *every* row in `TableB`. So, whilst the results may still not be what you want, are you sure that this hasn't vastly reduced the result set? Your question could be improved by adding *sample data* and *expected results*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it seems to return the desired results using `DISTINCT` with using `OR` instead of `AND` in the above join

Comment: @sam If there's an issue with `and` vs `or` it is almost certainly because the missing boolean connective you left out of your `where`s (which don't even parse) was an `or` but the answers guessed it was an `and`. Otherwise they & `distinct` are almost certainly irrelevant & only coincidentally working for some particular input, because they change the meaning from the 1st query. So if the code in the answers doesn't seem to work then it is almost certainly because you're not properly transcribing between your real code & schema and that of your question & the answers. (See my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Your first query only involves *one* left join of two tables, because all the `*=` comparisons involving the same pair of aliases are used for one left join. So we gather them into one `left join`'s `on`.

When there is only one pair of tables left joined in a `from`, a comparison of a column of the non-`*` table to a constant is also part of the left join criterion. So it also goes in the `on`:

> In a left join, the outer table and inner table are the left and right tables
>   respectively.

> If you submit a query with an outer join and a qualification on a column from the inner table of the outer join, the results may not be what you expect. The qualification in the query does not restrict the number of rows returned, but rather affects which rows contain the null value. For rows that do not meet the qualification, a null value appears in the inner table’s columns of those rows.

This gives:

```
SELECT 
    a.col1, a.col2, b.col1, b.col2, b.col3, b.col4
FROM
    tableA AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB AS b
ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2
AND b.col3 = "xxx" ??? b.col4 = "yyy"
```

For the full semantics see the [Transact-SQL® Users Guide for Adaptive Server® Enterprise 15.7](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/pdf/sqlug.pdf). In particular `*` left join semantics for some multiple-join queries changed as of version 12.0.

Answer (score 0):

NOTES:

- as philipxy has mentioned, providing a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be a big help in addressing your issue; in particular we have no idea what your source data looks like, the results you're currently receiving, nor the results you'd like to generate (so comments like "gives exactly the same results" means nothing to us since we have no examples to go by)
- as others have mentioned, you only need to `left (outer) join` to one copy of TableB (using 2/4 `on` clauses - more on this below)
- you haven't mentioned **which** Sybase RDBMS product you're using so I'm going to assume you're using Sybase ASE

For discussion purposes I'll create a couple tables and some sample data:

```
use tempdb
go

if object_id('tableA') is not NULL drop table tableA
go

if object_id('tableB') is not NULL drop table tableB
go

create table tableA
(col1   int
,col2   int
)
go

insert tableA values (1,1)
insert tableA values (1,2)
insert tableA values (2,3)
insert tableA values (2,4)
go

create table tableB
(col1   int
,col2   int
,col3   varchar(10)     null
,col4   varchar(10)     null
)
go

insert tableB values (1,1,'xxx','yyy')
insert tableB values (1,2,null,null)
go
```

With the old style of writing outer joins (ie, `*=` and `=*`), all `where` clauses are applied during the join operation, giving us the following results:

```
select  a.col1,
        a.col2,
        b.col1,
        b.col2,
        b.col3,
        b.col4

from    tableA AS a,
        tableB AS b

where   a.col1 *= b.col1
and     a.col2 *= b.col2
and     b.col3  = "xxx"
and     b.col4  = "yyy"
go

 col1        col2        col1        col2        col3       col4
 ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ----------
           1           1           1           1 xxx        yyy
           1           2        NULL        NULL NULL       NULL
           2           3        NULL        NULL NULL       NULL
           2           4        NULL        NULL NULL       NULL
```

While the first `tableA` record finds a match based on a) the 2 search argument (SARG) clauses (col3=xxx, col4=yyy) and b) the join clauses ...  the other 3 `tableA` records find no matches (primarily due to no matches for the 2 SARG clauses) so **all** `tableB` columns are filled in with NULLs.

We can generate the same result set with the following `left (outer) join` style query:

```
select  a.col1,
        a.col2,
        b.col1,
        b.col2,
        b.col3,
        b.col4

from    tableA as a
left
join    tableB as b

on      a.col1 = b.col1
and     a.col2 = b.col2
and     b.col3 = "xxx"
and     b.col4 = "yyy"
go

 col1        col2        col1        col2        col3       col4
 ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ----------
           1           1           1           1 xxx        yyy
           1           2        NULL        NULL NULL       NULL
           2           3        NULL        NULL NULL       NULL
           2           4        NULL        NULL NULL       NULL
```

Again, the SARG clauses are applied as part of the join operation.

Now, if the objective is to apply the SARG clauses **after** the join operation has completed, we need to move the SARGs into a separate `where` clause; to see how this works we'll first run the query with just the join clauses (ie, remove the SARG clauses):

```
select  a.col1,
        a.col2,
        b.col1,
        b.col2,
        b.col3,
        b.col4

from    tableA as a
left
join    tableB as b

on      a.col1 = b.col1
and     a.col2 = b.col2
go

 col1        col2        col1        col2        col3       col4
 ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ----------
           1           1           1           1 xxx        yyy
           1           2           1           2 NULL       NULL
           2           3        NULL        NULL NULL       NULL
           2           4        NULL        NULL NULL       NULL
```

By applying the SARG clauses as a separate `where` clause we can now filter out only the rows we want (namely, col3=xxx and col4=yyy) like such:

```
select  a.col1,
        a.col2,
        b.col1,
        b.col2,
        b.col3,
        b.col4

from    tableA as a
left
join    tableB as b

on      a.col1 = b.col1
and     a.col2 = b.col2

-- apply the SARGs **after** the join:

where   b.col3 = "xxx"
and     b.col4 = "yyy"
go

 col1        col2        col1        col2        col3       col4
 ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ----------
           1           1           1           1 xxx        yyy
```

So, at this point we can see that there a couple different result sets that can be generated from the `left (outer) join` style of query ... which result is 'correct' will depend on what final result you're attempting to generate ... which comes back to the comment about providing a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Before 12.0, non-`*`-side tables comparisons to constants were in `where` & `*`-side tables comparisons to constants were in the inner join; later there was a different rule based on the join graph.